# Referencing github actions environment variables within the env block

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, github-actions, workflow

I'm trying to create a new workflow file where I create an environment variable and use that variable in the value of some other environment variables, but it's not recognising it.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
   
env:
  dev_environment: "my-environment"
  working_dir_classic: "repo/${{ env.dev_environment }}/services/classic-service/"
  working_dir_cron: "repo/${{ env.dev_environment }}/services/my-cron-service/"
```

Can anyone help?

Above is what I have currently, but I'm unsure what needs fixing.